# Is there any way to determine what codec AVPlayer is using?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer

I have looked through all the header docs for AVPlayer, AVPlayerItem, AVAsset, etc and haven't found anything that could be used to gather information about the current codec being used by AVPlayer. Is it at all possible to ascertain the codec information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the codec through AVPlayerItem.tracks.assetTrack.formatDescriptions.

Something like

```swift
func printFourCC(_ fcc: FourCharCode) {
    let bytes: [CChar] = [
        CChar((fcc >> 24) & 0xff),
        CChar((fcc >> 16) & 0xff),
        CChar((fcc >> 8) & 0xff),
        CChar(fcc & 0xff),
        0]

    let result = String(cString: bytes)
    let characterSet = CharacterSet.whitespaces
    print(result.trimmingCharacters(in: characterSet))
}

for track in item.tracks {
    if let formats = track.assetTrack?.formatDescriptions as? [CMFormatDescription] {
        for format in formats {
            printFourCC(CMFormatDescriptionGetMediaSubType(format))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you won't be able to find this if an AVPlayer's currentItem fails to add any asset tracks, due to the codec not being supported. It'll just fail silently.